# match one list to another

Tags: perl, unix

I have a txt file with data that looks like this (TEST):

```
chr1_10524
chr1_10525
chr1_10562
chr1_8383722
chr1_201327234
chr2_123123
```

And another txt file with data that looks like this (DATABASE):

```
chrom chromStart chromEnd name
chr1 67071812 67170812 13_Heterochrom/lo
chr1 201326377 201330777 13_Heterochrom/lo
chr1 8383613 8389213 12_Repressed
chr2 120000 130000 1_Active Promoter
```

I wish to obtain an output file where the TEST is matched with DATABASE giving something like this:

```
chr1_8383722 12_Repressed
chr1_201327234 13_Heterochrom/lo
chr2_123123 1_Active Promoter
```

Can this be done on perl? Thank you!

Comment: How is `TEST` matched with `DATABASE` to generate the output you want?

Comment: `TEST` is basically a list of chr (chrom) with "_" separating the genomic position. I wish to obtain the output where if the `TEST` entry corresponds to a `DATABASE` entry range (within chromStart and chromEnd - inclusive) the output will provide the original entry from `TEST` and the corresponding name from `DATABASE`. Note that there are 2mill+ entries in `TEST` with different chr (eg. chr1 chr22 etc). I hope my explanation isn't too confusing..

Comment: None of the entry in your `TEST` can be used to generate the output that you given. Please update your question, given correct test inputs and the relationship between the inputs and output.

Comment: My apologies, this has been corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open(my $db, "<", "database.txt") or die "Cannot open < database.txt: $!";
open(my $tst, "<", "test.txt") or die "Cannot open < test.txt: $!";

my @database;

while (<$db>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split;
    push @database, \@fields;
}

while (my $line = <$tst>) {
    chomp($line);
    my ($chr, $pos) = split /_/, $line;
    # There is not unique key can be used to detect whether an entry is exist
    # in the database.
    foreach my $entry (@database) {
        if ($chr eq $entry->[0] && $entry->[1] <= $pos && $pos <= $entry->[2]) {
            print "$line $entry->[3]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
local $" = '_';

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    $hash{$_} = undef;
    last if eof;
}

while (<>) {
    my @cols = split;
    print "@cols[ 0, 1 ] $cols[-1]\n" if exists $hash{"@cols[ 0, 1 ]"};
}
```

Command-line usage: `perl script.pl TEST DATABSE [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter (without the square brackets) directs output to a file.