# Compare one value to a range of overlapping values on perl

Tags: perl

First file lists transcription factors and genomic regions associated with them. It is arranged chr, start position, end position, name of transcription factor. It looks like this:

```
chr1 10089 10309 ZBTB33
chr1 10132 10536 TAF7_(SQ-8)
chr1 10133 10362 Pol2-4H8
chr1 10148 10418 MafF_(M8194)
chr1 10382 10578 ZBTB33
chr1 16132 16352 CTCF
chr1 29308 29578 TAF1
chr1 29328 29558 HEY1
chr2 89802 90046 USF-1
chr4 91180 91560 CTCF
```

Note that many regions overlap.

Second file is straightforward. One column of queries. It looks like this:

```
chr1_10350
chr1_12090
chr1_16250
chr1_24512
chr5_1142341
```

I wish to obtain an output reporting the queries and their associated transcription factors. Like this:

```
chr1_10350 TAF7_(SQ-8)
chr1_10350 Pol2-4H8
chr1_10350 MafF_(M8194)
chr1_10350 ZBTB33
chr1_16250 CTCF
```

I tried a modified perl script from ([match one list to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900926/match-one-list-to-another)):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;

open(my $db, "<", "first_file.txt") or die "Cannot open < first_file.txt: $!";
open(my $tst, "<", "second_file.txt") or die "Cannot open < second_file.txt: $!";
open (OUT, ">Result.txt") or die "Cannot create output file";

my @database;

while (<$db>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split;
    push @database, \@fields;
}

while (my $line = <$tst>) {
    chomp($line);
    my ($chr, $pos) = split /_/, $line;
    foreach my $entry (@database) {
        if ($chr eq $entry->[0] && $entry->[1] <= $pos && $pos <= $entry->[2]) {
            print OUT "$line $entry->[3]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

But not only is it very slow, but repeated queries from the second file (e.g. chr1_10350) only result in one entry in the output rather than all of them.

Guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This looks like an interesting variant of the skyscraper problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try using following bash,execute it using system command

join -t' ' -1 1 -2 1 <(cat second_file.txt |awk '{gsub(/_/," ",$1);print $0}') first_file.txt|cut -d' ' -f1,2,5|awk -F' ' '{print $1"_"$2" "$3;}'

Answer (score 0):

I've execute your script on data you provided on my machine (Win7, ActiveState Perl v5.16) and it works pretty well.
Just one note: result data contains only 4 elements (andthis is correct):

```
    chr1_10350 TAF7_(SQ-8)
    chr1_10350 Pol2-4H8
    chr1_10350 MafF_(M8194)
    chr1_16250 CTCF
```